# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' firebase-app.js.1, firebase-analytics.js.1 & init.js.1 using react & firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm creating a project starting from the register components using react & firebase, I have installed firebase-tools and I've connected my app to the firebase cloud from the web using the appropriate means but I keep getting the 3 errors stated above in my console when trying to register a user from my react app.

My firebase sdk snippet is stored on the react app in a firebase.js file as shown below

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/database";
import "firebase/storage";


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxccccccccghgfg",
  authDomain: "ndjjjdjdjdnd.com",
  databaseURL: "ndjdjjdj.com",
  projectId: "bdjdkdksk",
  storageBucket: "bdjdjdkkdskjsnnsn",
  messagingSenderId: "hdjdjdjdjdnd",
  appId: "8bdndjjdjddcdnkkdef",
  measurementId: "Y-hdkdknd"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export default firebase;
```

I can't still register users from my react app to firebase. Please, I need assistance.